# Using find with -exec gzip and grep

Tags: unix, shell, find, grep, aix

I have a bunch of zipped up log files and I want to search them all for a string. I tried this but it's not working:

`find ./ -name "*.log.zip" -exec gzip -dc {} |  grep ERROR \;`

It's giving me:

```
find: incomplete statement
grep: can't open ;
```

What I want is, for each .log.zip file, unzip it and grep the output for "ERROR". Doing this on AIX, for what it's worth.

Comment: btw, I've managed to get the result I wanted by putting the -exec commands in a separate script and then using -exec script {} \; But I'd still like to know why the above doesn't work and if it's possible to do what I want without creating an intermediate script.

Comment: [That's why](https://superuser.com/a/1411724/432690).

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your syntax. Find is looking for `\;` or `\+`, but reads `|`. Grep is trying to open a file called ";". The difference between terminating -exec with a semicolon or a plus is running the command once for all files (+) and running the command once for every file (;).

Try this:

```
find ./ -name "*.log.zip" -exec zcat {} \+ | grep ERROR
# or
find ./ -name "*.log.zip" -exec sh -c 'zcat {} | grep ERROR' \;
```

Comment: The semicolon must be escaped with \ because it means something to the shell (end statement). The plus does not have to be escaped with bash.

Comment: The first option works if I use `gzip -dc` but not with `zcat`, which gives a `foo.log.zip.Z: No such file or directory` error. The second option I'd already tried, and doesn't work as the {} substitution doesn't work. If I use gzip it gives a `{}.gz: No such file or directory` for each file. For zcat: `{}.Z: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Then use the first version with `gzip -dc`. It's not entirely misguided to assume that most command line questions here are about GNU tools, specify the platform you are on and the version of the tools if that in not your case.

Comment: I specified that I was running on AIX in the original post. However, the question of gzip or zcat is not that relevant. I'm more curious as to why in your 2nd solution the {} substitution does not happen, especially as the `\+` find syntax cannot be applied to all such similar situations.

Comment: Sorry for being inattentive, clearly I didn't recognize the OS tag. My guess is that the find on AIX reads the option to the -c argument of sh as a literal string and does no substitution. You could try something like *-exec sh -c 'zcat '{}'| grep ERROR'*, but it's probably more effective to read the notes about -exec option in the manual than trying to "fool" the command. You could also use xargs, which has the -I flag (GNU find, but maybe AIX too) that specifies what `{}` should be. Such as: *find /dir | xargs -I% gzip -dc % | grep ERROR*.

Answer (score 0):

If you **don't** need to know which zipped log files contain the string:

```
find ./ -name "*.log.zip" -type f -exec gzip -dc {} + | grep ERROR
```

If you **do** want to know which files contain the string:

```
find ./ -name "*.log.zip" -type f -exec sh -c 'gzip -dc -- "$1" | grep -q ERROR' findsh {} \; -print
```

The first command finds the files and passes those filenames to the `-exec` option. I added the `-type f` restriction to the command to be sure that we're only matching files -- imagine someone running "mkdir foo.log.zip". `gzip` will decompress each one to stdout; we drop any `find` or `gzip` errors with the `2>/dev/null`; the stdout of that entire command is then piped through `grep`. The `+` syntax at the end of `-exec` will pass as many filenames as will fit, which minimizes the number of calls to `gzip`. Because gzip is sending all the file contents to stdout, `grep` now just has an incoming stream of bytes -- without filenames -- and will print any matching lines.

On the other hand, if you need to know the matching filenames, you have to capture that sooner in the pipeline.

On a GNU/Linux system (which has `zgrep`), you could do it directly:

```
find . -name "*.log.zip" -type f -exec zgrep -l ERROR {} +
```

This will pass (as many as will fit) filenames to `zgrep` which we then ask to print matching filenames (`-l option).

On an AIX system, you can recreate that functionality with a small shell script. The syntax can be a little intimidating, but let's break it down from the outside-in:

```
find ... -exec sh -c ' ... ' findsh {} \; -print
```

The above statement gathers one matching file at a time (`\;`) and sends it as an argument to the given `sh` script; if the script returns success, the filename is printed, otherwise it is not. The `findsh` portion is arbitrary text; it becomes the `$0` argument to `sh`, giving the inline shell script a name.

**Note:**

> The `{}` syntax needs to be **outside of the shell script**;
> otherwise, it could lead to arbitrary command execution. On AIX, the
> braces are not substituted *inside* the `-exec` parameter, so you
> would see "gzip: {}.gz: No such file or directory" errors if you tried
> it. On GNU/Linux, `find` *does* substitute the filename inside the
> shell script, which means if someone created a file named `$(touch foo).log.zip`, you would end up with a file named "foo" because the
> shell script initiates another layer of parsing on the filenames. See
> more at this UNIX & Linux question: [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156008/117549)

Once the filenames have been passed in one-by-one, the shell script is:

```
gzip -dc -- "$1" | grep -q ERROR
```

The filename is in `$1`, so we call `gzip -dc` on it. Out of habit, I try to mark the end of options before an arbitrary filename, just in case that filename begins with a hyphen -- or any other character -- that could be misinterpreted by the command as an option. Since our `find` command specifically starts the search with `./`, all the matching filenames will begin with that string, so they'll never look like options to gzip, but it's better to have safe habits. Once gzip has piped the contents, grep searches quietly for the string. If grep finds the string, the shell will exit successfully, allowing the subsequent printing; otherwise, it will cause the `-exec` to return a false/failure exit code, so the filename would not print.