# Redirection or pipe inside `find -exec`

Tags: linux, find, exec

Any "find -exec" guru's around.

I have a folder of files I need to send to `sendmail` (they appear in there when something bad has happened).

- The command

  ```
  find . -type f -exec sendmail -t < {} \;
  ```

  gives me

  ```
  -bash: {}: No such file or directory
  ```

  It doesn't seem to like the `<`.
- And this

  ```
  find . type -f -exec cat {} |sendmail -t \;
  ```

  gives me

  ```
  find: missing argument to `-exec'
  ```

  It doesn't seem to like the `|`.

What is wrong?

Comment: Also, can't believe I used the word folder instead of directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you'd like this redirection (`<`) or pipe (`|`) to belong to the inside of the `-exec … ;` statement. This doesn't work because they are handled by your shell before `find` even runs.

To make them work you need *another* shell inside `-exec … ;`. This other shell will handle `<` or `|`. Respectively:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'sendmail -t < "$1"' sh {} \;
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'cat "$1" | sendmail -t' sh {} \;
```

Note: `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'sendmail -t < "{}"' \;` is less complicated but wrong. This is explained here: [*Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618)

Comment: When I was using a command similar to this: 
`$ find -name "foo[1-5].tst" -exec echo "filenameis {}" >> {} \;`
It kept generating a file named '{}' with the echoed text.
After searching for few hours I found your answer, thanks for explaining in plain words :).
Just to be sure, is the following assumption valid?
The shell interprets the above command as follows
part 1:`find -name foo[1-5].tst -exec echo 'filename is:{}'` 
part 2: `(output of part 1) >> {}` #redirect the output of part 1 to the file named '{}'

Comment: @DoeMcBond I think the assumption is almost valid; you forgot `\;` in your explanation, the rest seems basically OK. [Redirection doesn't have to be at the very end](https://superuser.com/q/1335333/432690).

Answer (score -1):

In both cases your redirection is parsed by the shell, not by `find`, so you need to escape it:

```
find . -type f -exec sendmail -f \< {} \;
```

works as expected.

Comment: Just hangs for me when I try that.

Comment: -1. `sendmail` will receive the literal `<`. Compare `find /etc/fstab -exec echo \< {} \;` and `echo < /etc/fstab`.