# How to print all libraries in directories which use shared library?

Tags: linux, bash

How to print all libraries in directories which use shared library (mylibrary)? 
I tried:

```
ldd /usr/mt-60/apl/651/*.so |grep libmylibrary
```

But output is without library names:

```
    libmylibrary.so => /usr/aaa/libmylibrary.so (0x40017000)
    libmylibrary.so => /usr/aaa/libmylibrary.so (0x40016000)
```

Comment: Also asked at https://askubuntu.com/q/1139415/10127 -- stackoverflow is probably the better forum to ask.

Comment: If you would use FreeBSD you can use `ldd -f '%A %o\n'` (https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ldd). As I see the GNU `ldd` doesn't have `-f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /usr/mt-60/apl/651/*.so -exec sh -c 'ldd "$1" | grep -q libmylibrary' sh {} \; -print
```

The trick is `-exec` is also a test in `find`. In this case it tests the exit status of `sh` which is the exit status of `grep`; so `-print` will only work if `grep` finds anything.

Notes:

- We need inner `sh` to [make the inner pipe work](https://superuser.com/a/1411724/432690).
- Here all paths start with `/usr/mt-60/apl/651/`, so there will be no path that looks like an option (e.g. `-L`). In general you may want to use `find -- …` and `ldd -- …` in case there is such a path. It would be relevant if your pattern started with `*` or `?` or literal `-` (another way to deal with such unhandy pattern is to prepend `./` to it).
- The `*` wildcard is expanded by the (outer) shell, in general `find` will get multiple arguments before `-exec`. This may lead to `argument list too long` (or `no such file or directory` if there is no match). For this reason you may want `find` to do the matching:

  ```
  find /usr/mt-60/apl/651/ -type f -name "*.so" …
  ```

  where `*` is *not* expanded by the shell because it's quoted. Note this approach is recursive (investigate `-maxdepth` or see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/108618) if it's a problem).
- Omit `-q` to see the output from `grep` *before* the path to the respective file.