# How can I empty files at the same time with same paths?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, centos

I have a structure like this:

```
Father:
├───Charlie
│    └───lang.log
├───Ava
│    └───lang.log
├───Sophia
│    └───lang.log
...
```

I would like to clean up the scheme. I try:

```
cat /dev/null > Father/*/lang.log
```

but I have this error:

> -bash: */lang.log: ambiguous redirect

How can I empty all the files at the same time? Maybe with a single command.

Comment: Use `find` with `-exec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX solution, basic:

```
find Father/ -type f -name lang.log -exec sh -c 'true > "$1"' sh {} \;
```

`… -exec true > {} \;` wouldn't work, the inner shell is needed [because of redirection](https://superuser.com/a/1411724/432690). Note the shell part is not `sh -c 'true > {}'`, this version would be [flawed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).

---

POSIX solution, it should be faster thanks to spawning less `sh` processes if there are many matching files:

```
find Father/ -type f -name lang.log -exec sh -c 'for f; do true > "$f"; done' sh {} +
```

---

If you have `truncate` that can take many operands (note `truncate` is not required by POSIX):

```
find Father/ -type f -name lang.log -exec truncate -s 0 -- {} +
```

[`--`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618) is excessive here because in this particular case every path that comes from `find` must start with `Father/`, there's no risk any of them disguises as an option. In general however, using `--` before operands generated on the fly is good practice.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do that is using `xargs`:

```
find . -name lang.log | xargs -I {} sh -c "cat /dev/null > {}"
```

That will find any file with that name, then for each of them run `cat /dev/null > <filename>`.

Comment: Now there's a [command injection vulnerability](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).