# Write the output of xmllint to a log file, how?

Tags: linux, logging, xml, validation

With `xmllint` I check all XML files in the folder and if `xmllint` finds an invalid XML file there is an output.

My question: how can I write this output to a log file?

I found this command on the Internet:

```
find -type f -name "die_xml_datei.xml" -exec xmllint --noout {} \;
```

Here are my attempts:

```
find -type f -name "die_xml_datei.xml" -exec xmllint --output xml_not_valide.txt 2>&1
find -type f -name "die_xml_datei.xml" -exec xmllint --output xml_not_valide.txt {} \;
find -type f -name "die_xml_datei.xml" -exec xmllint --output > xml_not_valide.txt {} \;
```

Comment: I answered and did my best. Next time please provide more information: where does each attempt fail? what exactly in its output is wrong? E.g. you mentioned "all XML files" but used `-name "die_xml_datei.xml"`; I don't know if this was something to fix.

Answer (score 0):

The output you're after is printed to stdout. Each `xmllint` will inherit the stdout from `find`, so the simplest approach is just to redirect the stdout of `find`:

```
find -type f -name "*.xml" -exec xmllint --noout {} \; 2>xml_not_valide.txt
```

However if `find` prints anything to stdout then it will be written to the file as well.

A single `xmllint` can take more than one file to check. Reduce the number of new processes by running `xmllint` for as many arguments as possible:

```
find -type f -name "*.xml" -exec xmllint --noout {} + 2>xml_not_valide.txt
```

---

If you want to redirect stderr from `xmllint` process(es) but not from `find` then [you need to run an additional shell](https://superuser.com/a/1411724/432690):

```
: >xml_not_valide.txt
find -type f -name "*.xml" -exec sh -c '
   xmllint --noout "$@" 2>>xml_not_valide.txt
' find-sh {} +
```

Note I used `>>` because `find -exec sh … +` does not guarantee there will be only one `sh`. Note each redirection with `>` truncates the file. We want to truncate once at the very beginning, so we redirect the output of null command `:`; after this `>>` is the way to go.

---

If you need to know problematic files without the detailed output of `xmllint`, make use of its exit status. The tool will return non-zero if there are problems, zero otherwise. Use `-exec … \;` as a (negated) test:

```
find -type f -name "*.xml" ! -exec xmllint --noout {} \; -print 2>/dev/null >xml_not_valide.txt
```

Only if `! -exec …` succeeds (e.i. if `-exec …` fails, i.e. if `xmllint` returns non-zero), `find` will `-print`. It will print to stdout. We silence what `xmllint` prints to stderr and keep what `find` prints to its stdout.

You cannot do this with `-exec … +`. This time you must run one `xmllint` per file.

Comment: Hi,

thanks for your help, I'm using:

`find -type f -name "*.xml" -exec xmllint --noout {} \; 2> xml_not_valide.txt`
 
works very well.