# Search for files in many zip files

Tags: zip

I have many hundred zip files and want to find particular files in them. It is fairly easy the grep for filenames:

```
 find . -name "*.zip" -exec unzip -Z -1 {} \; | grep png
```

which would give all filenames *inside* the zip files. E.g.

```
icons/full/obj16/folder.png
icons/full/obj16/folderType_filter.png
icons/full/wizban/newfolder_wiz.png
```

But how can I prepend each line with the name of the zip file so I can actually find it? Something like so:

```
dir1/a.zip:icons/full/obj16/folder.png
dir2/icons.zip:icons/full/obj16/folderType_filter.png
myicons.zip:icons/full/wizban/newfolder_wiz.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this:

```
gexp='\.png$' aexp='{print f":"$0}' find . -type f -name "*.zip" -exec sh -c '
   for f do
      unzip -Z -1 "$f" | grep -i "$gexp" | awk -F "" -v "f=$f" "$aexp"
   done
' find-sh {} +
```

Explanation:

- I use `-type f` in case some directory (or other file that is not a regular file) accidentally matches `-name "*.zip"`. I don't want to try to `unzip` a directory.
- I use a shell invoked from `find -exec` to [run a custom pipeline for each file](https://superuser.com/a/1411724/432690) preselected by `find`.
- I use `-exec … {} +` to spawn far less shells than one per file. Now a single shell can get multiple paths as command line arguments, I loop over them with `for`.
- I pass static expressions I want to use with `grep` and `awk` in the environment. If I embedded them in the shell code, then I would need to obfuscate the command with additional escaping and/or quoting. Passing expressions separately is much cleaner. I could pass them as command line arguments to `sh`, but then I would need to save them in variables of the inner shell and `shift` properly before I could loop over actual paths (still better than quoting frenzy IMO).
- `find-sh` is explained here: [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)
- I use case-insensitive `grep -i`.
- Your pattern for `grep` was just `png`, it could match e.g. `stopngo`. I anchored it at line end and added a leading dot. The dot needs to be escaped because unescaped `.` matches any character in regex.
- `awk` adds the path of the currently processed file (and `:`) to the beginning of each line piped from `grep`. One may think `sed "s|^|$f:|"` where `$f` is expanded by the shell would work; but then the expansion of `$f` might break the expression (imagine it contained `|`, code injection is possible). If I let the shell expand `$f` in the `awk` code, it would be similarly flawed. With `awk -v "f=$f"` I store the path as `f` variable in `awk` (note `awk` variables and shell variables are independent concepts). Now `f` in `awk` cannot break the code because `awk` knows it's not code. Additionally the entire expression designed for `awk` is static, so I can pass it in the environment in the first place.

Comment: Worked as advertised!