# With a time sorted List, How to insert a checksum for each file?

Tags: linux, md5, md5sum

Time stamp example:
20211018_14:54:54.0596445490_Mon

Ubuntu 20.04.3 command below works, displaying

- Directories and
- Files and
- Hidden files with:
  Permissions, Time_Day, f or d, Path/fileName with

```
find . -printf "%M %TY%Tm%Td_%TT_%Ta %Y%p\n" |sort -k2 ;
```

Sort by time, column 2.
Most recent files at bottom, 4 examples:

```
-rw-r--r-- 20211001_13:02:16.0000000000_Fri f./Bash/awkCommnads.txt   
-rw-r--r-- 20211013_06:22:12.0000000000_Wed f./.HiddenFile_1.txt   
drwxr-xr-x 20211018_14:51:42.1712136500_Mon d.   
drwxr-xr-x 20211018_14:54:54.0596445490_Mon d./Bash
```

Said differently,
How to get 32 byte md5sum checksum for each file,
on Left side of above List that is sorted by time?
Example:

```
123456789T123456789w123456789Y12 -rw-r--r-- 20211001_13:02:16.0000000000_Fri f./Bash/awkCommnads.txt
```

Once md5 works then sha512sum.

Tip for testing:

```
setterm -linewrap off ; find . -printf "%M %TY%Tm%Td_%TT_%Ta %Y%p\n" |sort -k2 ; tput smam ;
```

For testing, one line per record, No Line wrap:

```
setterm -linewrap off ; Commands... ; tput smam ;
```

tput smam ; = linewrap on

Again,
With a time sorted List, How to insert a checksum for each file?

--

---

Comment: find . -printf "%M %TY%Tm%Td_%TT_%Ta %Y%p\n" -type f -exec md5sum + | sort -k2 ; Untested, untried but hopefuly not unloved.

Comment: The command __ find . -printf "%M %TY%Tm%Td_%TT_%Ta %Y%p\n" -type f -exec md5sum + | sort -k2 ; __ Gave error = 
find: missing argument to `-exec' __ on Ubuntu 20.04.3

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `md5sum` for each file (or rather for each regular [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690)). You run arbitrary commands from `find` with `-exec`. The problem is `find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \;` will print (i.e. `md5sum` will print) also the pathname and a trailing newline, and sometimes a leading backslash. You need to get rid of them before you proceed to `-printf`.

A straightforward way is with `cut` and `tr`. To execute `md5sum … | cut … | tr …` inside `find`, [you need a shell there](https://superuser.com/a/1411724/432690). Executing many processes per file is costly. You cannot use `-exec … {} +` because you need `md5sum` and `-printf` to take turns. We will save few processes if we manage to make the shell do the job of `cut` and `tr`.

For a single file (e.g. `/etc/fstab`) you can print its md5sum in the desired format, still without `cut` or `tr`, like this:

```
sh -c '
   exec 2>/dev/null
   sum="$(md5sum <"$1")" || sum="????????????????????????????????"
   printf "%s " "${sum%% *}"
' sh /etc/fstab
```

With performance in mind we hope `printf` is a builtin in your `sh`. The above command is designed to show question marks if `md5sum` fails. Useful links:

- [What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)
- [Parameter expansion and quotes within quotes](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690).
- [About `${sum%% *}`](https://superuser.com/a/1649184/432690).

Now let's build the command into your `find`. Like this:

```sh
find . -exec sh -c '
   exec 2>/dev/null
   sum="$(md5sum <"$1")" || sum="????????????????????????????????"
   printf "%s " "${sum%% *}"
' find-sh {} \; -printf '%M %TY%Tm%Td_%TT_%Ta %Y%p\n' | sort -k3
```

Notes:

- `sort -k2` became `sort -k3`.
- The command will try to run `md5sum` for files of any type. E.g. for a directory `md5sum` will fail and you will get question marks, this is acceptable. On the other hand, for a fifo `md5sum` may endlessly wait for data, this you don't want. Consider restricting `find` to regular files (simply add `-type f` as the first test) or fixing the command, so our `-exec` happens for regular files only:

  ```sh
  find . \( -type f -exec sh -c '
      exec 2>/dev/null
      sum="$(md5sum <"$1")" || sum="????????????????????????????????"
      printf "%s " "${sum%% *}"
  ' find-sh {} \; -o -printf '-------------------------------- ' \) \
  -printf '%M %TY%Tm%Td_%TT_%Ta %Y%p\n' | sort -k3
  ```

  The sequences of `?` or `-` characters are of the length of any md5sum, so they align nicely.
- Newlines in pathnames will confuse your `sort`. If you can, use null-terminated strings. E.g. with GNU `sort` in my Kubuntu:

  ```
  find … -printf '…\0' | sort -z … | tr '\0' '\n'
  ```

Comment: Above answer = 262 characters from _find . \( -type_to_sort -k3_ 
Above answer: 1. Detects if file modified, time changed. Good. 
2. Detects if hidden file was modified, time changed. Good. 
3. Sorts files, latest time to List bottom. Good. 
4. Inserts a Hash, a checksum md5sum for Files & Hidden. Good. 
5. Gives no Dir. hash. Gives 32 minus signs like --- for Directories. Disrelish. 
Ideal is to also have a Hash, a checksum md5sum, for Directories. For clarity, No Hash for Directory means __ -------------------------------- drwxr-xr-x 20211018_14:51:42.1712136500_Mon d./Comm __

Comment: @joseph In Linux [you cannot read a directory as a byte stream](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156020/108618), so you cannot compute md5sum from it. You can compute a checksum from *something else*. Your now deleted "answer" suggests that for directories you want a checksum from the output of `ls` or so, but *your question does not specify this*. How to compute a sum differently for directories and non-directories is an issue orthogonal to what you originally asked. IMO asking a new question is better than [creating a chameleon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/355310).

Comment: How to run answer as a 1 Line command?  Above answer = 262 characters.

Comment: @joseph What difference does it make? Written in one line it still will be `find … | sort …`, only far less readable; and it will take about the same number of characters.

Comment: The difference a 1 Line makes is Less keystrokes.  Answer has 6 Lines.  A one Line answer would save 5 keystrokes.  Less effort, Less keystrokes, to move 1 Line about relative to other commands.  The 6 Line answer broke when converting it to 1 Line.

Comment: @joseph Are you telling me you *typed* my code? To really save keystrokes, learn how to copy and paste.